# CSS: How do you keep this Div to the right of a float?

Tags: css

In my code below, case #1 works correctly. The "advice-area" div stays to the right of the "rating-box".

However, case #2 does not work when the text extends beyond one line. This causes the "advice-area" div to move below the "rating-box"

What is the best way to fix this? Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
    .wrapper {
        width: 400px;
        list-style: none;
    }
    .row {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
        padding: 15px  0;
        font-size: 14px;
        clear: both;
    }
    .rating-box {
        float: left;
        height: 70px;
        position: relative;
        width: 60px;
    }
    .thumbs {
        float: right;
        width: 20px;
    }
    .number {
        position: absolute;
        top: 16px;
        left: 5px;
    }
    .advice-area {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 35px;
    }
    .advice-content {
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    }
    .advice-action {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .add-box {
        display: inline;
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
    .add-box a {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .share-button {
        display: inline;
        margin-left: 30px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .flag {
        display: inline;
        margin-left: 30px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
   </style>
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="wrapper">
        <li class="row">
            <div class="rating-box">
                <div class="thumbs">
                    <div> Up </div>
                    <div> Down </div>
                </div>
                <div class="number">1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="advice-area">
                <div class="advice-content">Case #1: This is correct</div>
                <div class="advice-action">
                    <div class="add-box"><a href="#">Plan</a></div>
                    <div class="share-button"><a href="#"> Share </a> </div>
                    <div class="flag"> <a href="#">Flag</a> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li> 
        <li class="row">
            <div class="rating-box">
                <div class="thumbs">
                    <div> Up </div>
                    <div> Down </div>
                </div>
                <div class="number">2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="advice-area">
                <div class="advice-content">Case #2: But this really long text does not want to stay right next to the "Up" and "Down" links</div>
                <div class="advice-action">
                    <div class="add-box"><a href="#">Plan</a></div>
                    <div class="share-button"><a href="#"> Share </a> </div>
                    <div class="flag"> <a href="#">Flag</a> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd restrict the width for the `.advice-content` or `.advice-area` div (or whatever div is around the content you're floating).

When you enter text into a floated div the div will auto-size its width accordingly, and if it expands too wide it'll automatically wrap over to the next line. Think about how wrapping works for words in text.

So, all you need to do is to restrict the width of that particular div, and it'll never grow wide enough to wrap to the next line.

Unless if you're in IE: in which case it'll do whatever the hell it wants ;)

Answer (score 0):

Floating elements, rather than inline blocks, are probably what you want in this situation. I managed to get what looks like a useful outcome by moving the number `div` above the up/down `div` in the code, and then floating both to the left. I then tweaked the margins until the spacing looked decent.

CSS changes:

```
.number {
    float: left;
}

.thumbs {
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.advice-area {
    margin-left: 80px;
}
```

HTML changes:

```
<div class="rating-box">
    <div class="number">1</div>
    <div class="thumbs">
        <div> Up </div>
        <div> Down </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

limit the width on .advice-content and it will show how you want it to.

```
.advice-content { 
    font-size: 16px; 
    margin: 0 0 10px 0; 
    width:300px;
}
```

worked for me in IE7 & 8 / Firefox / Opera / Chrome / Safari